# Cross-validation of arima forecast in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I would like to make sure that I am understanding R's `fit` and `summary` functions.

Here's how I'm using them for a time series with 100 data points which are divided into train and test samples:

```
x = ts(MyData)
train = x[1:80,1]
test = x[81:length(x), 1]
fit = arima(train, order=c(1,1,0))
summary(fit, test)
```

Am I correct in my thinking that `summary` will compare the fitted model for time steps 81 through 100 to the actual values `x[81], x[82], ..., x[100]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`methods(summary)` shows the following list:

```
> methods(summary)
 [1] summary.aov                    summary.aovlist*            summary.aspell*
 [4] summary.check_packages_in_dir* summary.connection          summary.data.frame     
 [7] summary.Date                   summary.default             summary.ecdf*
[10] summary.factor                 summary.glm                 summary.infl*
[13] summary.lm                     summary.loess*              summary.manova
[16] summary.matrix                 summary.mlm*                summary.nls*       
[19] summary.packageStatus*         summary.PDF_Dictionary*     summary.PDF_Stream*
[22] summary.POSIXct                summary.POSIXlt             summary.ppr*          
[25] summary.prcomp*                summary.princomp*           summary.proc_time  
[28] summary.shingle*               summary.srcfile             summary.srcref      
[31] summary.stepfun                summary.stl*                summary.table 
[34] summary.trellis*               summary.tukeysmooth*        summary.yearmon*   
[37] summary.yearqtr*               summary.zoo*
```

As you can see there are no methods for the `Arima` class (which is the class of your `fit` object), so this is not what happens (i.e. you are not comparing your forecasts with your actual values). You are using `summary.default` from the above list.

You can see this from the following too:

```
a <- arima(USAccDeaths, order = c(1,1,0))
identical(summary(a), summary(a, USAccDeaths[1:100]))
#[1] TRUE
```

There is no difference between `summary(a)` and `summary(a, USAccDeaths[1:100])`.

To compare using RMSE:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- arima(USAccDeaths[1:50], order = c(1,1,0))
preds <- as.vector(forecast(fit, h = 10)$mean)
RMSE <- sqrt(mean((preds - as.vector(USAccDeaths[51:60])) ^ 2))
RMSE
#[1] 2056.483
```

The closer it is to zero the better your model.

Comment: So what is the correct way to check the forecasts against the test data set?

Comment: There is no ultimate correct way. I use the RMSE usually to assess the fit. But there are a number of ways out there like MAPE or MAE. These can be easily calculated from the residuals. Here is a [link](https://heuristically.wordpress.com/2013/07/12/calculate-rmse-and-mae-in-r-and-sas/) too.

Comment: I understand that there is no single best metric, but I still don't understand how to compare the model predictions to the actual test data, using any metric, in R.

Comment: I provided an example. You need package `forecast` to forecast and then you can calculate the RMSE as well. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is more like what I was looking for. But is there not some standard function to get a summary or forecast errors through a function like `accuracy()`?

Comment: `accuracy ` does not work with `arima`, only with `Arima` which comes from `forecast` package. If you use base `arima` there aren't many things you can do automatically (or apart from using the RMSE I showed you), but you could use `Arima` which makes things easier. You can read more about it [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8)